# What books discuss general rules of Tanach?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, product-recommendation, jewish-books, tanach

In particular, I am looking for books that deal with philosophical and linguistic questions on Tanach, such as:
If there is seemingly no reason to place one passuk before another, is it reasonable/necessary to justify why one precedes the other? 
Why was the Torah seemingly written in such an obscure manner?
Does פשט account for every letter in the Torah or is דרש (and maybe רמז and סוד) necessary for that?
What is the precise distinction between פשט and דרש and is there an overlap between the two?
What is the precise meaning and difference between biblical conjuctions (e.g. ו) and prefixes and suffixes?
A discussion of the sources that disagree about the role of שמות הנרדפים.

(Just like there are sifrei kelalim on gemara, I am looking for a "sefer kelalim" on Tanach. Alhough, to my knowledge, sifrei kelalim on gemara don't generally deal with philosphical and linguistic questions on gemara, perhaps something like that exists on Tanach?)

Comment: @DoubleAA Re-close as too broad?

Comment: @Doniel for what benefit?

Comment: @DoubleAA is my question still too unclear? (i'm new here so i'm not exactly sure how this works)