# Who teaches Tanakh?

Tags: torah-study, tanach, grammar-dikduk

I would like to study Tanakh in its entirety with a focus on dikduk, hebrew language, basic meaning/commentators, and possibly cantillation. I am not very self-motivated so I would prefer to join a program/course that offers this, or to study with a tutor. Do you know of any resources or tutors that can help? I'd want to study under someone who is Orthodox.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95582/13438

Comment: @Alex that is actually an old post of mine but that question is different than the present one..I'm looking for a person who can teach basics of Tanakh

Comment: There are programs like Partners in Torah and Torahmates that set people up with tutors. I think normally it's about once a week. If you want more you could hire a tutor.

Comment: I've done a lot of tutoring in past. If your interested, lmk.

Comment: @N.T. I would definitely be interested. How can I contact you?

Comment: natanthaler@gmail.com

Comment: Not in it's entirety, but Rabbi Breitowitz has a Nach series https://www.kolhalashon.com/New/Ravs.aspx?Lang=English&English=True&RavID=-1&ROrder=-1&FID=288648&HideMenus=False and https://outorah.org/series/5149